# An algorithm to plot a linear graph onto an exponential graph

Tags: algorithms, graphing-functions

**Does anybody know an algorithm to accurately plot data points from a linear graph onto an "exponential" graph?**

Notably, I'm not even sure that I'm using the right terms, so bear with me.

What I'm trying to do is calculate the risk of any given investment, so that the measure of risk increases exponentially as the ratio of free capital (FC) to invested capital (IC) swings in favour of IC.

Below is a hypothetical and some crude images of graphs to further explain what I mean/want to do.

**Hypothetical condition: Our balance is $10,000.**

If we use the formula **[FC minus IC]**, any given scenario can now be plotted on a linear graph (Graph B), which is of course equivalent to Graph A, but I'm looking to transpose potential data points of Graph A or B onto Graph C.

Any ideas? Any mathematicians or data scientists out there?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: No, there are no mathematicians or computer scientists here. All the answers are provided by English majors with ouija boards. 
Please use standard mathematical notation and learn the fundamentals of MathJax, see [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @CarlChristian i posted the question elsewhere and copy and pasted ;) i don't have much free time, hence posting this question instead of looking into it more in depth myself, but i'll def take a look the next time i get a few free moments